# SharePoint Designer Workflow- In a list workflow how to compare one field value from current list to another list

Tags: workflow, designer

I working on a list wotkflow and want to compare one field value from current list to another list , for having same value or not to update the status for workflow?

how can I give that in if condition to compare these two list field?

Comment: Do you have a unique identifier for the list item you want to compare to?

Comment: No, I don't have unique identifier in a list , I just want to match one field value from current list to another for having same value if has then workflow status should be Approved.

Comment: Yes, you will need a way to identify that specific list item. Other than a single unique field value you can do a REST query and filter based on multiple columns.

Answer (score 2):

On the 'Field Data to Retrieve' section you can select the list and field you are wanting to compare. The 'Find the List Item' section allows you to filter to a specific item in the list. In this example you are saying I want the `Title` field from the `Calendar` list where the `ID` field in that list is equal to `12345`.

If you do not give a unique identifier you will get a warning that if more than one result is returned only the first item will be used.

[image: Lookup]